# Get the size of each white object in an image python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, size, mask

I am trying to get the size of each separate object in this image so that I can separate them by size.  My aim is to be able to loop through them and separate them by size. I have looked everywhere and can't really find anything anywhere. I have tried connected component analysis but I am unsure of how to retrieve size values from it.

```
_, lab = cv2.connectedComponents(img)
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [connectedComponentsWithStats.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponent#connectedcomponents)

```
# Choose 4 or 8 for connectivity type
connectivity = 4  
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)

num_labels = output[0]
stats = output[2]

for label in range(1,num_labels):
    blob_area = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]
    blob_width = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    blob_height = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
```

`num_labels` will give the total number of labels. You can use `stats` matrix to retrieve size of each blob by iterating through each label.

Comment: perfect than you, do you know what the difference between a connectivity of 4 or 8 does?

Comment: @mdumple 4-way connected pixels are neighbors to every pixel that touches one of their edges. 8-way connected pixels are neighbors to every pixel that touches one of their edges or corners. 
This will help: http://aishack.in/tutorials/pixel-neighbourhoods-connectedness/